# Uploading large zip file to google drive using drive SDK giving error

Tags: php, google-drive-api, drive

Hello I am trying to upload a large zip file to drive. I tried `new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload()` but it gives me this error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Exception: Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 200)

I don't know why it is behaving so can anyone tell me what could be the issue or why my script is throwing this exception.

Here is my code,

```
$AT = Helper::get_Settings('google_token');

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('Client_ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('Client_Secret');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

    $client->setAccessToken($AT);

    // Making a new drive service
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    // Making directory structure into google drive
    $dirs = explode('/', $dir);
    $parentid = '';
    foreach ($dirs as $new_dir) {
        $dirSt = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $dirSt->setName($new_dir);
        $dirSt->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
        if ($parentid != '') {
            $dirSt->setParents(array($parentid));
        }
        $new_file = $service->files->create($dirSt, array(
            'fields' => 'id'));

        $parentid = $new_file->id;
    }

    // Uploading Backed up files
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $file_path = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/' . $fileName . '.zip';
    $fileSize = filesize($file_path);
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    $mime_type = 'application/zip';

    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'name' => $fileName,
        'parents' => array($parentid)
    ));

    $client->setDefer(true);

    $request = $service->files->create($fileMetadata);

    // Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload($client, $request, $mime_type, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $media->setFileSize($fileSize);

    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($file_path, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
        $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    $result = false;
    if ($status != false) {
        $result = $status;
    }

    fclose($handle);
    $client->setDefer(false);
```

Now why it is throwing this exception I am stuck here.

Comment: does it work with a smaller file ?

Comment: Nope, with smaller files I have another code that works perfect for smaller files but for larger files it gives this exception

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload($client, $request, $mime_type, null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).